# Show available template parameters when running dotnet new

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, command-line-interface

I want to see all available template parameters when I run command `dotnet new MyTemplate`.

How can I do it? I know when I miss some required param then I see it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `--help` to the end.

```
dotnet new MyTemplate --help
```

This shows the specific help information for that template. `--help` can be used on other levels of `dotnet` commands.

Answer (score 0):

You can do `-l`  or `--list`  to see all available templates:

```
dotnet new -l
```

In general if you want to know the available options for a command you can call the help:

```
dotnet new -h
```